# wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) using first_or_create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to generate a set of users automatically in my app

```
email = 'me@example.com'      
generated_password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
user = User.first_or_create({email: email}, {email: email, password: generated_password})
```

I'm getting a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)` error

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

insert the **password_confirmation** field, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
user = User.where(email: email).first_or_create(password: generated_password)
```

Note the 'where' takes the first parameter and 'first_or_create' takes your second parameter.